# Issues with Range.FormulaLocal and textstring in formula

Tags: excel, vba

When I finally had figured out that I can use my own language with Range.FormulaLocal in stead of Range.Formula I was very excited!

The possibilities are endless. But, I am encountering a problem with textstrings in formulas.

This code works just fine:

```
Range("I5").FormulaLocal = "=ALS(A5=1;H5;0)"
```

But these codelines are not working:

```
Range("I5").FormulaLocal = "=ALS(A5="x";H5;0)"

Range("I6").FormulaLocal = "=ALS.FOUT(VERT.ZOEKEN(A2;'betaaltermijnen.xlsx'!tabel;3;ONWAAR);"")
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: You need to escape double quotes (`"`) in VBA: `"=ALS(A5=""x"";H5;0)"`

Comment: replace `"x"` with `""x""` and `;"")` with `;"""")"`

Comment: Comintern & Slai! Thanks both of you for the quick answers

Answer (score 3):

You're accidentally ending your strings early...

First line:
If you have a variable `x` which you want to include in the string, then use `&`

```
Range("I5").FormulaLocal = "=ALS(A5=" & x & ";H5;0)"
```

If instead you're trying to have the string `"x"` then you must use an additional quotation mark before each in-string quotation mark. This is called an escape character.

```
Range("I5").FormulaLocal = "=ALS(A5=""x"";H5;0)"
```

This way, when VBA sees `""`, it treats it as the start or end of *a quote within a string*

By the same reasoning, your second line becomes

```
Range("I6").FormulaLocal = _
    "=ALS.FOUT(VERT.ZOEKEN(A2;'betaaltermijnen.xlsx'!tabel;3;ONWAAR);"" "") "
```

Where I've used the `_` underscore to continue the line without it getting too long, because the last 6 characters are the important bit!

Comment: Thank you very much Will! It is a comprehensive answer!